# Is Redirecting to another path means unmounting?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am new to react and redirecting to another path and restricting some other user to directly enter in `/main` path. I am checking , `if yes ..` it will redirect...

So when I am redirecting it will redirecting to `/login` page and this is redirecting twice.

Now when I reached on login and filled my credentials and got the token, now the field I set i.e. authenticate is `yes` because `componentWillUnmount()` did not called.

So this means components did not mounted. And as I put all the credentials right as I said I field (authenticate is 'yes') then flow will not redirected to `/main..` it will be redirected to same page `/login` and gave an error.

```
class Main extends Component { 

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { userInfo: '', onlineUser: '', authenticate: 'no' };
    }

    async getUsers() {
        let user = await apiGateway.getUserInfo();
        alert(' did Mount1');
        alert(user);
        if(user == null) {
            this.setState({ authenticate : 'yes' });
            return;
        }
        else {
            this.setState({ userInfo : user.data });
        }
    }

    async setUpOnlineUsers() {
        let online = await apiGateway.getOnlineUsers();
        alert('did Mount2');
        if (online == null) {
            this.setState({ authenticate: 'yes' });
            return;
        } 
        else {
            this.setState({ onlineUser: online.data });
        }
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        this.getUsers();
        this.setUpOnlineUsers();
    }

    async componentWillUnmount() {
        alert('unmount');
    }

    render() {
        const { authenticate } = this.state;
        alert(authenticate + ' render');

        if (authenticate === 'yes') {
            console.log('Redirect');
            return <Redirect to='/login' /> ;
        }
        const { userInfo } = this.state;
        const { onlineUser } = this.state;
        console.log(onlineUser);
        return (
            <div className='Main'>
                <div className='Main-header'>
                    <Header userInfo = {userInfo}/>
                </div>
                <div className='Main-chat'>
                    <Chat onlineUser = {onlineUser}/>
                </div>
                <div className="Main-container">
                    <Image imageArray = {imageArray}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Main;
```

** index.js **

```
 class App extends Component{

    render(){
        return(
            <Router>
                <div>
                    <Route path ='/login' component={Login}/>
                    <Route path = '/register' component={Register}/>
                    <Route path = '/' component={Main}/>
               </div>
            </Router>
            );
    }
 }

 export default App;
```

Comment: After reindenting of your code, we can see a `}` is missing.

Comment: where i am missing } this  ????

Comment: no, sorry, my fault. I forgot to reindent the return too.

Comment: no..problem..Can you please give me some solution of this problem ??

Comment: share your `index.js` where your routes are set

Comment: updated with index.js